# Use case diagrams

Tags: uml, use-case

What are the free options for creating use case diagrams under Windows? I need some simple use case diagrams for a school project.

Comment: don't forget to check the diagrams the various tools generate, some of them won't be standard UML...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why install anything when you can use free online tools such as

http://creately.com/

http://yuml.me/

http://www.gliffy.com/uses/uml-software/

Comment: Seems to be a rip off to use online tools but not be able to keep the diagrams unless you pay. :/

Comment: @jlg: ***they*** need to eat too!

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple options, but not yet mentioned are:

- [Cacoo](https://cacoo.com/) - web tool for creating various diagrams,
- [Dia](http://projects.gnome.org/dia/) - standalone toolf for creating diagrams, with Win32 version also available in downloads,

Answer (score 2):

When I remember right, there is a community edition of Magic Draw (the leading app?): https://www.magicdraw.com/

I already used Poseidon (Community) and ArgoUML, both not really convenient.

Recently I found a great tool called yEd: http://www.yworks.com/de/products_yed_about.htm This can be run via web start. Not really UML but use cases are perfect with yEd.

Apparently there is already something in Eclipse: http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/?project=uml2 I did use it to test. Not yet convincing usability.

Wikipedia says: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools

Edit!

Don't miss the stackoverflow search top right of this page.

Answer (score 2):

There's a pretty nice tool called UML Pad.

http://web.tiscalinet.it/ggbhome/umlpad/umlpad.htm